# why is observable not notifying if block in knockout?

Tags: knockout.js, coffeescript

The knockout if binding does not get notified when the selection changes. When the selection changes, if the selected country has 'eu' set to "1", I want something to happen.

```
<select data-bind="options: countries,
    optionsText: function(item) {
    return item.country_name
    },
    value:selectedCountry">
</select>

<!-- These *ARE* all updated when country selection changes -->
<div data-bind="visible: selectedCountry()">
    <span data-bind="text: selectedCountry().eu"></span>
    <span data-bind="text: selectedCountry().country_name"></span>
    <span data-bind="text: selectedCountry().country_code"></span>
</div>

<!-- This is *NOT* updated -->
<!-- ko if: selectedCountry().eu === "1" -->
    <span>You selected country from EU
    </span>
<!-- /ko -->
```

'countries' (sample) below.

```
{
    "countries": [
        {
            "country_code": "BD",
            "country_name": "Bangladesh",
            "eu": "0"
        },
        {
            "country_code": "BE",
            "country_name": "Belgium",
            "eu": "1"
        }
     ]
 }
```

***UPDATE***

I am using CoffeeScript

```
@selectedCountry = ko.observable()
@countries = ko.observableArray []
```

Comment: Is `eu` itself an `observable`?

Comment: Maybe because `"eu": "0"` is not equal to `1`?

Comment: @RichardMacarthy, it *will* be equal to 1 when you choose an option in the `<select>` dropdown.

Comment: @RichardMacarthy it can be though, depending on selection - updated question to be more clear

Comment: @haim770 no, it is not

Comment: It does seem to work. See http://jsfiddle.net/9t3y1pk6/

Comment: @haim770 I was not declaring countries properly as an observableArray in CoffeeScript...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me on this fiddle. Not sure what the difference between my code and yours is, as we cant see you JavaScript.

https://jsfiddle.net/xggu9Lv2/7/

```
var countries =  [
        {
            "country_code": "A2",
            "country_name": "Satellite Provider",
            "eu": "0"
        },
        {
            "country_code": "A2",
            "country_name": "Satellite Provider",
            "eu": "1"
        }
     ]

var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.countries = ko.observableArray(countries);
    self.selectedCountry = ko.observable(null);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel()); 

<select data-bind="options: countries,
    optionsText: function(item) {
    return item.country_name
    },
    value:selectedCountry">
</select>

<div data-bind="visible: selectedCountry()">
    <span data-bind="text: selectedCountry().eu"></span>
    <span data-bind="text: selectedCountry().country_name"></span>
    <span data-bind="text: selectedCountry().country_code"></span>
</div>

<!-- ko if: selectedCountry().eu === "1" -->
    <span>You selected country from EU
    </span>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: I was not declaring countries properly as an observableArray in CoffeeScript